# How To Get Control Property by "String Name"?

Tags: vb.net, string, object, controls

i have been created buttons and textboxs by **coding** in next loop, 
the result

```
'T(x).Name = "text_1"
'T(x).Name = "text_2"
'T(x).Name = "text_3"
'....

'B(x).Name = "button_1"
'B(x).Name = "button_2"
'B(x).Name = "button_3"
'...
```

and i want to get textbox property whene i click the button,
i can get button property when click like `button_1.Name.ToString`
but i cant get the text_1,2,3 .... property.

i do some trick by split function button_1.Name.ToString and get the last number 
and add it to the textbox name like `"text_" & button_1.Name.ToString` but i can't convert this string to object.

**Update**

Here's the code I'm using to load the controls in the loop:

```
C_A_TEXT(x) = New TextBox() 
C_A_TEXT(x).Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill 
C_A_TEXT(x).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(270, 5) 
C_A_TEXT(x).Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0) 
C_A_TEXT(x).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(70, 27) 
C_A_TEXT(x).TabIndex = 5 
C_A_TEXT(x).Name = "NEW_RECHARGE_COUNT_TEXT_" & x
```

**Update 2**

Here's some more code:

```
AddHandler C_A_BUTTONS(x).Click, AddressOf C_A_BUTTON 

Private Sub C_A_BUTTON(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Dim thisButton As Button = sender Dim A = CType(Me.Controls("NEW_RECHARGE_COUNT_TEXT_1"), TextBox) 
    MsgBox(A.Text.ToString)  'Error!
End Sub
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can access the controls by name via the `Form.Controls` property, for instance:

```
Dim text1 As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("text_1"), TextBox)
```

Comment: i want to select controls by sting name ("NAME")

Comment: That is precisely what I demonstrated.  In my example, the string name is `"text_1"`.

Comment: i know but when i try `MsgBox(text1.Name.ToString)` result `Error` :(,
i can't get any property .

Comment: You'll need to show how you are creating/loading the controls in the loop.

Comment: Do the controls actually show on the form?  I don't see where you are ever adding them to the form?

Comment: Please don't try to post multi-line code examples in comments.  it never ends well :)  I added the code to your question.

Comment: Again, please don't do that.  When posting code, always add it to your original question where it will be properly formatted.  I have added that second bit of code to your question again for you.

Comment: You never answered my questions: *Do the controls actually show on the form? I don't see where you are ever adding them to the form?*

Comment: sorry for that, yea i can see it after created and i can add handles and everything, but i want get the textbox property from the button sub .. not from the textbox sub

Comment: If you can see the control, then you must be, somewhere in code that you didn't post, adding it to either the form or a container control of some sort, such as `Me.Controls.Add(...` or `Frame1.Controls.Add(...`.  You need to find that code.  The reason is, you need to search for the control by name in that same container's `Controls` collection property, whichever container that happens to be.  Alternatively, when you are creating the controls, you could just add them to a `Dictionary(Of String, TextBox)` object and just retrieve it from that dictionary when necessary.

Comment: thanks i found the way to get it, i created all of this with arrays and next loop...

so i can get the number of the key form button name 'split function' and put it ;) `Dim x() As String = Split(sender.name.ToString, "_")` and `Dim thisText As TextBox = C_A_TEXT(x(3))`

Comment: NullReferenceException is occuring but I have a control with the name

Comment: @MdAshrafulIslam Try `Me.Controls.Find`. Does that find it?

Answer (score 10):

As a quick useful tip to note, you don't seem to have to specify the type of control within the CType statement for purposes of accessing a control on your form. I came across this when trying to access multiple types of form controls, such as buttons and textboxes, all with the same line of code.

```
CType(Controls("NAME_OF_CONTROL"), Control)
```

Note that, rather than specifying exactly what type of control, such as 'TextBox' or 'Button', you simply state 'Control'. This allows you to universally change any type of control, without needing to specify its type.

I couldn't find this anywhere else, so I thought I'd share it!

Answer (score 9):

Below is the code.

```
Dim oObj As Object = Me.Controls.Find("control name", True).FirstOrDefault()
Obj.Property = Value
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  Thank you @thewaywewere.

In addition,one can then use CType to onvert the object to the desired control type.

Dim oObj As Object = Me.Controls.Find("control name", True).FirstOrDefault()
txtbox = CType(oobj,TextBox)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sometext As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("sometext "), TextBox)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

The title of the thread and your description of the problem at hand seem a little different from each other.

To answer your *title* (to find a control by its name) use the following:

```
Dim myControlToFind = LayoutRoot.FindName("NAMEOFCONTROL")
```

More information on this method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) .

To answer the *description* of your issue as (to access a code generated control after it is clicked) do the following:

In the loop where you are creating the control(s) add the following handler

```
Addhandler YOURCONTROL.Clicked, AddressOf Textbox_Clicked
```

...and then this will handle the click event

```
Private Sub Textbox_Clicked(sender as object, e as RoutedEventArgs)

Dim tbClicked = Ctype(sender, TextBox)
'You can now access any of the properties of the textbox, for example

Dim txt as String = tbClicked.Text
Dim name as String = tbClicked.Name
Dim height as Double = tbClicked.Height

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer assumes WPF.  Since Hesham never specified, you *may* be correct in that assumption, but I rather doubt it.

Comment: Actually, given the comment he just added to my answer, I'd say it's pretty much certain that he is using WinForms.

Comment: thanks for your time but here `Dim tbClicked = Ctype(sender, TextBox)` i want replace `sender` to some string name like  `"TEXT_BOX_1"` because i want click a button not a textbox .

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. This does:

```
Dim selVal As String = CType(Form.FindControl(myListName), DropDownList).SelectedValue
```