# Use a String As Object Name

Tags: vb.net, string, object

How can I change a picture box's image when I only have a string that has the name of the picture box. (it probably doesn't really matter that it's a picture box or that I am changing it's image)

For example:

```
"picturebox1".image = myimage      'how would I get this to actually set an image for picturebox1?
```

Comment: You'd need to use reflection.

Comment: How did you come to this point?  I'm guessing there's a problem with the design somewhere else which would be better fixed than to continue with this approach.  Why do you have the name of the variable as a string?

Comment: I just realized that this is a duplicate. the answer is here: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name?rq=1)
Thanks for the super fast replies

Comment: @user1727470: `Controls.Find` method suggested by @Douglas is better, because it allows you to traverse the tree of controls. `Me.Controls` in the answer you linked only takes top level (direct children) into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always prefer using DirectCast instead of CType.  This is also safer because it won't crash if it doesn't find a picturebox with that particular name.

```
Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("picturebox1", True).FirstOrDefault(),  PictureBox)
If pb IsNot Nothing Then
    pb.Image = myimage
End If
```

Comment: I like the OfType extension method:  `Dim pb = Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  The DirectCast will throw an exception if it finds a control of that name but a different type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Dim pic as PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls("PictureBox1", PictureBox))
pic.Image = myimage
```