# VB how to access object using objectname + string

Tags: vb.net

New to VB  and trying this

```
    Private Sub setTextboxFocus(x As TextBox)
       x.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(221, 221, 221)
       x.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(5, 73, 138)
       x.Name & "Padding".BackColor = Color.FromArgb(221, 221, 221)
```

Assuming the name of x is "textbox1" , the last line is suppose to reference a panel with the same name & "Padding" , so "textbox1Padding" which obviously isn't working like other languages.  How is this done in VB?  I'm sure its simple but cant see anything online regarding it.

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? If the latter, use FindControl(). If the former, think custom control instead of related names.

Comment: the answer is simple and is already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name)

Comment: Its Winforms,  i will consider making a textbox with padding but i need to know how to access an object with obj.name + string for other things too

Comment: I know of  me.controls but is this the only way?  If I write  textbox1Padding.backColor it works fine , I know this is referencing the object but is there no other way to do that with out starting at Me When i already know the name?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way, other than *Reflection*, which is even more involved.