# Access vba pass variable into code

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I'm in Access 07 trying to pass a variable to a line of code.  The purpose is to make an array of field names and then loop over the array performing the same action on each field.  I've simplified it down to avoid any potential problems with the array or the loop.
In any other language I am familiar with it would be pretty simple, but I can't seem to format it in VB.

```
Me.FeildName.Locked = True
```

would be the static code, and I think the variable code would look something like this:

```
Dim Temp as String
Temp="FieldName"
Me.[Temp].Locked = True
```

but it keeps giving me an error that says "can't find the field '|' referred to in your expression", so it's not reading the value of the variable.
How do I get it to read the variable in the command?

Alternatively, I've tried to concatenate strings into a line of code:

```
Dim CodeLine As String
Dim TestName As String
TestName = "FieldName"
CodeLine = "Me.[" & TestName & "].Locked = True"
```

This creates a string that looks like functional code but how would I run it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Get Control Property by "String Name"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Me` is a form, you need

```
Temp = "FieldName"
Me.Controls(Temp).Locked = True
```

Comment: "Controls()"... that's what I needed!  I knew there was just some nomenclature I didn't know.  I had tried "Fields()" and a couple others I found with no success.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Dick Kusleika's answer is the way to go, but for completeness' sake, you can do also something like this:

```
For i = LBound(strControlNames) To UBound(strControlNames)
    CallByName Forms![MyFormName].Controls(strControlNames(i)), "Locked", VbLet, "True"
Next
```

strControlNames would be the array with your control names.

Comment: This looks similar to my code but I want to experiment with the differences to see if I can learn anything.  What does the "VbLet" do?
I can't find that in the book I have or even a web search.
Thanks

Comment: @charles_m80: CallByName can run a method or sets a property value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278760%28v=office.15%29.aspx).  vbLet is a constant which is telling the function that we want the property in question, Locked, in this case, to be set to True (as opposed to vbGet, which would indicate we want to extract the value, for example).  If you have done any Class programming in VB or VBA, Let/Get is how you set/get custom you custom class properties.