# VB.net Using a string to change something.Text

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to work in VB.net for school and have encountered a problem.
The program works like this:
I've got a store page with buttons to buy them, they each have a name with the item and "_buy" after it. So if I wanted to buy a laptop, I'd press a button named laptop_buy.

What I want then is to make the event call the fuction Buy(laptop), so I can use the laptop ID later on.

I also have things named like laptop_level and laptop_price. I want to change them when I click the button. So I created this function:

```
Private Sub laptop_buy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles laptop_buy.Click
    Buy("laptop")
End Sub
```

And

```
 Function Buy(ByVal item)

    Dim itemlevel As String = item + "_level.Text"

    itemlevel += 1

End Function
```

So this should change the laptop_level.Text when I click laptop_buy.
But it isn't working.

Help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: This answer should get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15077120/242584

Comment: Yes it is working. It's just not doing what you think it is. itemLevel is a local string variable, what should it be?

Comment: asp.net? winforms? wpf?

Comment: That'd be `Me.Controls(item + "_level").Text = (CInt(Me.Controls(item + "_level").Text) + 1).ToString()`, but are you sure your teacher expects you to do this? That is a pretty bad way of managing this kind of data.

Comment: Maybe `DataGridView` with `DataGridViewButtonColumn` will be better approach fro this kind of cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ControlCollenction.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get your label.
Then you need to cast it's text value to Integer (I recommend using [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method for that) and then add 1 and return the result to the label text. Something like this should do the trick.

```
Sub Buy(ByVal item As String)
    Dim level As Inetger
    Dim ItemLabel as Label;
    Dim ChildControls As Control() = Me.Controls.Find(item & "_level", True)
    If ChildControls.Length > 0 Then
        ItemLabel = ChildControls(0)
    End If
    If not isNothing(ItemLabel) AndAlso Int32.TryParse(ItemLabel.Text, level) Then
        ItemLabel.Text = (Level + 1).ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:** Code was written directly here, and it's been a long time since my vb.net days, so there might be some mistakes in the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this the first thing tomorrow!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :(
Giving me the error:
`Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Windows.Forms.Control' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'.`

Answer (score -1):

Your trying to add 1 to a string.

A 'String' is a series of text characters, so the '1' in your text box is the character '1' not the number. You need to first conver the text into an 'integer'

Try:

```
dim itemlevel as integer = TryCast(item, integer)
   If IsNothing(itemlevel) = false then
     itemlevel = itemlevel + 1
     Return itemlevel
   end if
```

[MSDN TryCast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx)

Comment: Did you even read the question? What do you expect to get from casting "laptop" to an integer?

Comment: Yep, it won't convert to an integer.

Comment: "itemlevel" suggests the 'quantity' of laptops, hence the 'itemlevel +=1 "    "So this should change the laptop_level.Text when I click laptop_buy. But it isn't working."

Comment: So...
click()....
IF IsNumeric(laptop_level.text) = true then laptop_level.text = laptop_level.text + 1
....Did you read the question before down voting?

Comment: `itemlevel` is the OP's attempt to somehow reference the `Text` property of a control with dynamic name (first part of which is contained in `item`).