# Multiple textboxes with same name

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a homework assignment in which I need to take names from a text file and add them to an array. Then for each index in the array add it to a specific textbox.

So I called my textboxes: `txt_Name1`, `txt_Name2`... and so on.

So I had 5 items in my array and I want item at index `0` to be added to `txt_Name1`, index `1` to `txt_Name2` (and so on), but I don't know how I would make the loop to go through this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Get Control Property by "String Name"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name)

Comment: I wouldn't really say I'm trying to find its string name. What I'm trying to do is populate the specific textbox with the array[specific index]. I'm trying to go through a loop since these textboxes have the same name just the number on the end is different.

Comment: Create an array of your TextBox and put them in the same order in which you want to populate them. Then you can use the same loop index to read from your string array and write in the Text property of the textboxes in the textbox array

Comment: Oh I didn't know that was a thing you could do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate variable names with a Me.Controls bit

Me.Controls("Textbox" & i).Text

That will allow you to loop through control names