# Place string after Me

Tags: string, vba, replace

I'm new to VBA so this ought to be a simple one. I'm trying to call a sub that has a string with it. This string needs to be placed after the Me. It should look like `Me.StringHere` VB gives me an Compile error saying member or data method not found. The string is an actual textbox control so it should work in theory. I'm just starting to experiment with calling subs so it's probably something quite simple I'm not sure about. Here is the code.

```
Sub CueBannerActive(ControlToUpdate As String)

'Activates the cue banner font settings
    With Me.ControlToUpdate
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Font.Name = "Verdana"
        .ForeColor = &H80000011
    End With

End Sub 'CueBannerActive(ControlToUpdate As String)
```

Here is how I am calling it.

```
CueBannerActive "txbShipToNameOne"
```

Comment: `With Me.Controls(ControlToUpdate)`

Comment: Awesome - thanks! I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: You may like to also consider whether passing an actual control to the subroutine, rather than just the name of a control, might be a better implementation approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Get Control Property by "String Name"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to change the variable for Object, you need to do that, because the VBA doesn't understand the 'txbShipToNameOne' as an object, so you cannot use it, and as I could understand you're using a Form, trying to change label/objects. So the sub going to be like:

```
Sub CueBannerActive(ByVal ControlToUpdate As Object)

'Activates the cue banner font settings
    With ControlToUpdate
        .Font.Italic = True
        .Font.Name = "Verdana"
        .ForeColor = &H80000011
        .Caption = "I was here"
    End With

End Function
```

I called it in a button, as you can see below:

```
Private Sub cmdButton_Click()
    Call CueBannerActive(Me.txbShipToNameOne)
End Sub
```

`Me.txbShipToNameOneis` the object that you want to change, so if you want to reuse the code for a lot of labels you can do it.