# Read data from dynamically created text-box

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to collect data after creating dynamic text-box with vb.net

```
Private Sub btn_OK_lines_number_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    Handles btn_OK_lines_number.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Z As Integer
    Z = 150
    If IsNumeric(txt_lines_number.Text) Then
        Int32.TryParse(txt_lines_number.Text, x)
        For i = 1 To x
            Dim newTB As New TextBox
            Dim newLB As New Label
            newLB.Name = "lbl_workstation_number_line" & i
            newLB.Text = "Nbr Work Station in Line" & i
            newLB.Size = New Size(190, 20)
            newLB.ForeColor = Color.White
            newLB.Font = New Font("consolas", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            newLB.Location = New Point(20, Z + i * 30)
            newTB.Name = "Textbox" & i
            newTB.Size = New Size(170, 20)
            newTB.Location = New Point(200, Z + i * 30)
            Me.Controls.Add(newTB)
            Me.Controls.Add(newLB)
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("please enter a number")
        txt_lines_number.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Bilel. You've explained what you're trying to do, but not what's going wrong with it. What issue are you running into?

Comment: Since you never asked a question, it's hard to say for sure, but I think this is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name).

Comment: Hi Cory, i didn't know how can i call each value from textbox to save it on DB : i m using this function to save data from other normal cases :  

            mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workstation", TEXTBOX.TEXT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you just have one row, and only create one TextBox. You set the name here:

```
newTB.Name = "Textbox" & i
```

where the resulting TextBox is named `Textbox1`. The problem is you can't just reference the identifier `Textbox1` directly in your code, as you do with `txt_lines_number`. You can't even reference it as a member of the class (`Me.Textbox1`). This name didn't exist at compile time, and so it's not an identifier you can use, and it's not a member of the class at all. There was never a matching `Dim` statement for that name.

What you can do, though, is look again in the `Controls` collection where you added the TextBox to the form:

```
Me.Controls("Textbox1")
```

or

```
Me.Controls("Textbox1").Text
```

You may also need to cast the value to a TextBox:

```
Dim box As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls("Textbox1"), TextBox)
MessageBox.Show(box.Text)
```

Remember that case matters here.

Further saving this in a DB is out of scope for one question. There are as many ways to do that as there are programmers in the world. You should make your own attempt first, and come back here with a new question when you run into specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
this is my attempt and it is done !

```
Dim userInput As TextBox = Form1.Controls.Item("TextBox" & i.ToString)
mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workstation", userInput.Text)
```

:D

Comment: [`AddWithValue()` isn't often the best choice.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you creating dynamic amount of input controls, **right tool for the job** will be `DataGridView` control.

Create a class to represent your data

```
Public Class LineInfo
    Public Property Number As Integer
    Public Property WorkStationNumber As Integer
End Class
```

Create `DataGridView in the form designer.

```
Private Sub btn_OK_lines_number_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_OK_lines_number.Click
    Dim linesAmount As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(txt_lines_number.Text, linesAmount) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("please enter a number")
        txt_lines_number.Text = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Create class instance for every line
    Dim lines = 
        Enumerable.Range(1, linesAmount)
                  .Select(Function(i) New LineInfo With { .Number = i })
                  .ToList()

    'Set lines as DataSource to the DataGridView
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = lines
End Sub
```

DataGridView will display all lines and provide input fields to update work station numbers.

You can access updated lines later by casting `DataSource` back to the `List`

```
Dim lines = DirectCast(Me.DataGridView1.DataSource, List(Of LineInfo))

' Now you can access all data and save it to the database
Dim parameters = 
    lines.Select(Function(line)
                     Return new SqlParameter With 
                     {
                         .ParameterName = $"@workstation{line.Number}",
                         .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                         .Value = line.WorkStationNumber
                     }
                 End Function)
         .ToList()

myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)
```

You can freely change style, font colors of different columns in the datagridview.