# How can I write a loop to replace this if statement for different buttons

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I have an Access datatable named `A`. It has 90 rows and each row has 2 columns as follows:

[image: primary key as autonumber and yes/no field]

I have a vb form that has 90 green buttons and code:

```vb
Private Sub _1st_Floor_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection(myConnString)
    Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM A WHERE Busy=True", myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(myCommand.ExecuteReader)
    If dt.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString = 1 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
        Button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red
    End If
    If dt.Rows(1).Item(0).ToString = 2 Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Red
        Button2.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine, but I don't want to repeat the same `If` block over and over again for 90 buttons. How can I write a loop with just one set of code for all 90 buttons?

Comment: Are there any other buttons of any kind on the form? Do the buttons have some common container, such as a GroupBox or Panel? Is there a common naming convention for the buttons that could be used to set them apart from other buttons that might be in scope?

Comment: the buttons are named like Button1 Button2 Button3 and there are other buttons on the form itended to do other things

Comment: and also Button1 has text "1"
button2 has text "2" and so
and there no container or group box

Comment: Then the first step is to fix that. You want something that will set the buttons apart, so you can reference them in code as a group.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your records and find the corresponding buttons:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
  Dim buttonName as String = "button" & row(0).ToString()
  Dim cntrls() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(buttonName, True)
  If cntrls IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim btn As Button = TryCast(cntrls(0), Button)
    If btn IsNot Nothing Then
      btn.BackColor = Color.Red
      btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red
    End If
  End If
Next
```

This is dependent on the buttons' naming scheme being consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own "words" :) maybe not the most efficient way but I just wanted to write this by reusing your code as much as possible...

```
Private Sub _1st_Floor_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection(myConnString)
    Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM A WHERE Busy=True", myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(myCommand.ExecuteReader)

    For index As Integer = 1 To 90
        If dt.Rows(index - 1).Item(0).ToString = index.ToString Then
            Dim button As Button = CType(Me.Controls("Button" + index.ToString), Button)
            button.BackColor = Color.Red
            button.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name) to get controls by name `String`