# How to create a Loop to push Values to different TextBox with Similar Labels names and Change their text?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to this VB. I'm building an application where I need to fill some 48 text boxes with 4 sets of similar names like

```
L1onHHxx
L1onMMxx
L1offHHxx
L1offMMxx
```

Where xx is a number from 1 to 24 for each label.

What I'm trying to do is calculate some values based on the user input and fill the text boxes with results.

```
Private Async Sub Line1Calc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Line1Calc.Click
    Dim Cycle_Time As Integer
    Dim Cycle_Count As Integer
    Dim srtHH As Integer
    Dim srtMM As Integer
    Dim stpHH As Integer
    Dim stpMM As Integer
    Dim inDelay As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lineONHH As New Label
    Dim lineONMM As New Label
    Dim lineOFFHH As New Label
    Dim lineOFFMM As New Label
    'Dim controls = GetAllTextBoxes(Me)
    'Line1Tab
    Cycle_Time = CInt(L1Time.Text)
    Cycle_Count = CInt(L1Count.Text)
    srtHH = CInt(L1ONHH.Text)
    srtMM = CInt(L1ONMM.Text)
    stpHH = CInt(L1OFFHH.Text)
    stpMM = CInt(L1OFFMM.Text)

    inDelay = (24 / CInt(Cycle_Count))

    L1onhh1.Text = srtHH
    L1onhh1.Text = srtHH
    L1offhh1.Text = stpHH
    L1offmm1.Text = stpMM

    For i = 2 To (Cycle_Count)
        srtHH += inDelay
        stpHH += inDelay
        lineONHH.Name = "L1onhh" & i.ToString()
        lineONMM.Name = "L1onmm" & i.ToString()
        lineOFFHH.Name = "L1offhh" & i.ToString()
        lineOFFMM.Name = "L1offmm" & i.ToString()
        lineONHH.Text = srtHH
        lineONMM.Text = srtMM
        lineOFFHH.Text = stpHH
        lineOFFMM.Text = stpMM

        ' To Check if the labels name are correct
        Box1.Text = lineONHH.Name 
        Box2.Text = lineONMM.Name 
        Box3.Text = lineOFFHH.Name 
        Box4.Text = lineOFFMM.Name 

        Await Task.Delay(1000)
    Next
End Sub
```

Here when I pass the value of the New label to Box 1,2,3 & 4 for test purposes they are correct but the values don't appear on the respective text boxes.

[image: The Screenshot of the Screen for reference.]

Please can anyone point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bit hard to answer with any certainty, gut feeling is you might want to look at the [Forms.Controls Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)  you can query this to find your target controls.  Many examples of how on this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076975/how-to-get-control-property-by-string-name/15077120#15077120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close, with a few assumptions made.
It assumes you have constant textbox naming pattern.
Assumes you want hour and minute in string.
Switch that structure to a DateTime if you want it in that format.

```
    'class to hold all your time value entries
    Private Class TimeValue
        Public Property HourValue As String
        Public Property MinValue As String
    End Class
    'class for each control time slow and its associated timevalues
    Private Class ControlTime
        Public Property TimeSlot As String
        Public Property OnValue As TimeValue
        Public Property OffValue As TimeValue
    End Class

    'method to set control values
    Private Function SetControlValus(controlTimeItem As ControlTime) As Boolean

        'find the control
        Dim OnHourTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(String.Concat("L1onHH", controlTimeItem.TimeSlot), False)(0), TextBox)
        OnHourTextBox.Text = controlTimeItem.OnValue.HourValue

        Dim OnMinTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(String.Concat("L1onMM", controlTimeItem.TimeSlot), False)(0), TextBox)
        OnMinTextBox.Text = controlTimeItem.OnValue.MinValue

        Dim OffHourTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(String.Concat("L1offHH", controlTimeItem.TimeSlot), False)(0), TextBox)
        OffHourTextBox.Text = controlTimeItem.OffValue.HourValue

        Dim OffMinTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(String.Concat("L1offMM", controlTimeItem.TimeSlot), False)(0), TextBox)
        OffMinTextBox.Text = controlTimeItem.OffValue.MinValue

        Return True

    End Function

    Private Sub Test()

        'set up some results
        Dim results As List(Of ControlTime) = New List(Of ControlTime)
        results.Add(New ControlTime() With {.TimeSlot = "01",
                    .OnValue = New TimeValue() With {.HourValue = "08", .MinValue = "56"},
                    .OffValue = New TimeValue() With {.HourValue = "08", .MinValue = "58"}})

        results.Add(New ControlTime() With {.TimeSlot = "02",
                    .OnValue = New TimeValue() With {.HourValue = "09", .MinValue = "14"},
                    .OffValue = New TimeValue() With {.HourValue = "09", .MinValue = "29"}})

        For Each controlTimeItem In results
            SetControlValus(controlTimeItem)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub TestControlTimeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestControlTimeButton.Click
        Try
            Test()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Andrew Mortimer thanks for the code but when I run it gives me the error message of "An Error Occured: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: I see the casing is different between my code and yours: "L1onhh" vs "L1onHH". Update the Find with your control naming and it should be ok.

Comment: Hi  @Andrew Mortimer, Thanks this code worked it was the **{.TimeSlot = "01",** here the 01 I replaced with just 1 and it worked.

Comment: Pleased to hear it. Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes this code serves the purpose if all the Textboxes are directly on the form, But does not work when all the textboxes are inside a Tab or Group Box. Then it gives the same above error.

Comment: You'd then need to change the Find `searchAllChildren` parameter to True...

Comment: Ok, Now it works thanks. I'm marking this as Solved.